# Error when attempting to use max_element to figure out the highest number in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, int, max

```
int a = max_element(highesthuman[0], highesthuman[2]); 
  if( win > loss)
  {
    cout << "You won " << (win-loss) << " games more than the computer did! You used " << a  << "     the most."; 
  }
}
```

The above array is given by

```
int humanrock = 0;
int humanpaper = 0;
int humanscissors = 0;
int highesthuman [3] = {humanrock, humanpaper, humanscissors};
```

When running my whole program I get an error saying "invalid type argument of unary". I looked this up but was not able to understand "pointers" or what people were referring too.

Comment: Maybe read [some documentation for `std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element).

Comment: If you're expecting that adding one to `humanrock` will change `highesthuman[0]`, it won't.  The `higesthuman[3]` array is three integer values that are completely distinct from `humanrock`, `humanpaper` and `humanscissors`.  It would probably help a lot if you explained exactly what relationship you want between the `humanrock` etc. trio, and the `highesthuman[3]` array.

Answer (score 3):

[std::max_element()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/) accepts two iterators as parameters, and returns an iterator. In your case iterators are pointers. So you should change

```
int a = max_element(highesthuman[0], highesthuman[2]);
```

to

```
int a = *max_element(highesthuman, highesthuman + 3);
```

Comment: Thank you. To clarify, since it knows highesthuman is already an array, it knows to start at 0 and I must put the ending point? Also, I was curious to the *. I have not learned what that does yet.

Comment: @MarkHubrig it "knows" only types of parameters passed (by template instantiation). You pass `highesthuman` - it's the beginning of the range, and `highesthuman + 2` - it's the end of the range.

Comment: @MarkHubrig `+ 3` to be more precise

Comment: @AntonSavin you just saved my life!!